# Spring Sleuth ignore "get /**" either by pattern or "mvc.controller.class"

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, jaeger

TLDR : How can we ignore sending traces to jaeger (or zipkin) where the header is "get /**", and if that is not possible ignore sending traces where  "mvc.controller.class" is "RequestHttpRequestHandler"

We have a app which uses spring sleuth, in this app we have some requests sent to jaeger which result in get the header as "get /**" and the controller for these cases are "RequestHttpRequestHandler"

[image]

However it seems that we cant use a simply "**" path filter and after debugging the spring code a bit each specific pattern comes up in the skip section as follows

[image]

Comment: Which version of sleuth are you using?

Comment: We are using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:2.2.2.RELEASE`